# Access values from a property file with a one to one relationship

Tags: java, properties-file

How can I retrieve values from property file which has a one to one relationship?

I have two values in my properties file.

```
apptoservice=Auto,RL,SC
clienttoapp=autouser,rluser
```

Above is a 1-1 relation between app and client.i.e appl = Auto, need to retrieve autouser.

In my Java class i can get app name, based on this retrieve client from property file.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: if its position based, like auto at pos 0 in apptoservice relates to autouser at pos 0 in clienttoapp, then its easy.. get property value, split on `,` and match indices.

Comment: @Shail016 :based on one value can we fetch other ? , like if its Auto then autouser ?

Comment: can you upload your java code as your question is confusing and not clear what you are trying to do. you may get answers which may not set you req as we may interpret your question based on assumption

Comment: seems not possible in your case, there is no relation format between values except for their positions corresponding to their keys.

Comment: @Shail016:Is using index and fetching is a good approach, or can I maintain like Auto=autouser RL=rluser like three entries in properties and fetch based on key . Can you suggest which approach is better

Comment: both will work, if your read property file only once and store the values in memory in a map etc, you don't need to read file and perform processing repeatedly.